# Why do i keep getting the same error when trying to route my angular pages?

Tags: angular, router

I was following a tutorial about routing pages in angular but i've been getting the following error

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: No component factory found for HomeComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

By following other examples found in stack overflow i've tried adding "entryComponents" to my routing but it gives a different error:

```
HomeComponent cannot be used as an entry component.
```

What exactly is wrong here?

This is my routing file
**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/views/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  entryComponents: [
    HomeComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: The entryComponent would be in AppModule, not the routing module. Make sure it's also in the `declarations` block there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to `declarations` section too

> Component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'] //Optional
})

export class HomeComponent{}
```

> app.module

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    HomeComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: now i am getting the following:
Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'AppRoutingModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Do you have `@Component` on the top of `HomeComponent`?

Comment: I added how HomeComponent should look like